# What are the best / recommended video cards for WPF

Tags: hardware

I am looking to get a "recommended video card" for working with reasonably intensive graphics in WPF. I know a lot of cards with enough onboard memory will handle it but is there a particlar set which is "more suited"?

This has been moved from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220288/what-are-the-best-recommended-video-cards-for-wpf-closed becuase it's not appropriate apprently.

Really the question is what features (apart from most expensive) should I be looking for in a graphics card to run WPF.
Is a vector graphics card a better option?

Comment: You're gunna hate this, but the place that this question *really* belongs is on superuser.com - Stack Overflow constantly shovel questions here that belong on superuser. Bad news - superuser.com is not open to the public yet :(

Comment: Agreed! I'm going to try to answer it anyway... He may not have a beta pass for Superuser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are not really any recommended video cards, If you get yourself a descent graphics card (in the +£40 range), it should be able to handle anything that WPF can throw at it.

WPF is done by Direct X, and nearly every card can handle that. My onboard Intel graphics can display quite a fancy WPF program without breaking a sweat (I think it also does a lot of work in the cpu) so I don't see why even a cheap graphics card would have a problem.

Answer (score 1):

For the best answer I think you're going to need to define "reasonably intensive" a bit better, but the baseline of hardware accelerated Direct3D 9 with 128 MB of video RAM should be perfectly adequate for all but the most extreme cases.  This ain't Doom 3!